# Prove or disprove: for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, for any $r_1,r_2, \ldots, r_n \in R$ then there exists $a_j, 1 \leq j \leq n$ such that $r_j > 1$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have to prove or disprove:

For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, for any $r_1,r_2,\ldots, r_n \in R$ such that $\forall i, 1 \leq i \leq n, r_i > 0$  and such that $r_1  r_2 \cdots r_n = 1$, if there is an $i$, $1 \leq i \leq n$ such that $r_i < 1$, then there exists a $j$, $1 \leq j \leq n$ such that $r_j > 1$.

Hi if i can get some help for this one here please I'm new to discrete math sorry for my lack of knowledge thank you.

Comment: The product o fall others is $=\frac1{r_i}$

Answer (score 4):

if we suppose that for each $j$, $1 ≤ j ≤ n$ with $j≠i$, then we have $r_j ≤ 1$ . given that  $\forall j$     ${r_j>0}$
we can conclude that $r_1 × r_2 × ... × r_n ≤ r_i <1$ . contradiction.

Comment: Way to go, ***+1, endorsed!***  Now bring it home with MathJax and $\LaTeX$ify the thing!  Cheers!

Comment: Very well done, wish I could upvote again! ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help